# Need to remove duplicates from JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working with a JSON array and I am trying to remove duplicates from being posted on the HTML page when I run the loop. Currently I see both images with the same category pizza on the page. How can I make it so it shows only one pizza category with an image? I want to hide the others.
Hoping someone can show me what I need to do. Below is my code:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var url = 'path to json';

  $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    var data = (json);
    var images = '';

      var uniqueNames = [];
   
      //retrieve values from json file
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      if($.inArray(item, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(item)
         images += '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">' + '<img class="img img-responsive img-hover imgCategory" src="' + (item[0].imageURL) + '">' + '<h1>' + (item[0].category) + '</h1>' + '</div>';
     
         });
      //append results to div
      $('#images').html(images);
  });
})();
```

```js
/*JSON Sample */
[
  [{
    "category": "pasta",
    "imageURL": "path to image"
  }],
  [{
    "category": "pizza",
    "imageURL": "path to image"
  }],
  [{
    "category": "pizza",
    "imageURL": "path to image"
  }]
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
var arr = [], //collect id values 
    collection = []; //collect unique object

$.each(json_all, function (index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.id, arr) == -1) { //check if id value not exits
        arr.push(value.id);//push id value in arr
        collection.push(value); //put object in collection to access later
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried that but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: currently i am trying this approach   var uniqueNames = [];
   
      //retrieve values from json file
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      if($.inArray(item, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(item)
         images += '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">' + '<img class="img img-responsive img-hover imgCategory" src="' + (item[0].imageURL) + '">' + '<h1>' + (item[0].category) + '</h1>' + '</div>';
      });

      //append results to div
      $('#images').html(images);

Comment: will update code at top as well